# What's correct "let's change it (to or for) another day?"

Tags: prepositions

When I am asking to change the catch-up to another day, 
what's correct:

> let's change it to another day

or

> let's change it for another day

?

Comment: I don't know what a 'cath-up' is, but an appointment is changed _to_ another day.

Comment: Let's postpone it to another day.

Comment: Change it *to* another day. Although, you could reschedule/leave it *for* another day

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

- Let's catch-up another day
- Let's change our appointment **to** another day
- Let's make an appointment **for** another day

To:
"to" is used to indicate the direction of a place, person or thing.

"for" is used to indicate:

- The use of something
- Time or duration
- In place of "because of"

https://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/prepositions-of-to-for.aspx